# Verilog error - [USF-XSim-10] Unknown option '-'

Tags: verilog, vivado

As in title - i'm making clock in **Verilog (Vivado)** and keep getting error when trying to run simulation:

```
"[USF-XSim-10] Unknown option '-', please type 
               'launch_simulation -help' for usage info."
```

Implementation and synthesis were ok.

**Testbench code:**

```
timescale 10ns / 10ns

module Zegar_Testbench;

    reg Uruchom;
    reg Reset;

    wire [5:0] Sekundy; 
    wire [5:0] Minuty;
    wire [4:0] Godziny;
    wire [4:0] Dni;

    Zegar_zaliczenie (.Uruchom(Uruchom), .Reset(Reset), .Sekundy(Sekundy), .Minuty(Minuty), .Godziny(Godziny), .Dni(Dni));
    initial Uruchom = 0;
    always #50000000 Uruchom = ~Uruchom;

    initial begin
            $monitor ("Jest dzień %d Jest godzina %d:%d:%d", Dni,Godziny,Minuty,Sekundy);
            Reset = 1;
            #1;
            Reset = 0;
     end
endmodule
```

**Options:**
 Project Options:-

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to launch the simulation? Or the options you've set in Vivado (which I believe is the IDE, according to a quick Google search). It looks like there's a typo involving the '-' character, but we can't help with the typo unless we see what's been typed.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry about that.

Comment: I was hoping it would be something generic, but because there's no actual "-" character in the code you posted, someone more familiar with Verilog/Vivado will have to help you - sorry!

Comment: I believe Verilog only supports ASCII. `ń` is not on the standard ASCII table, so I'm guessing the file is in a UTF (unicode) format. This my be part of the problem. The "verilog option" from your project option looks odd because options are typically one word with no white space; if you selected it from a drop-down this you should be okay, but if you typed it in then refer to the manual.

Comment: "Verilog option" was generated automatically by vivado... I think i solved the problem but new error appeared:

 [USF-XSim-62] 'compile' step failed with error(s). 

It's the same testbench code.
And yes - i deleted the "ń".